# OpenLiberty not accepting JMS connection from JMSToolBox

Tags: java, ssl, open-liberty, jmstoolbox

This is a continuation of what I'm [attempting to achieve here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340286/connecting-jmstoolbox-to-jms-app-on-openliberty/74346308?noredirect=1#comment131313721_74346308), connecting JMSToolBox to OpenLiberty.

I followed the instructions in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340286/connecting-jmstoolbox-to-jms-app-on-openliberty/74346308?noredirect=1#comment131313721_74346308) successfully.

I'm getting the following in message.log in JMSToolBox when I attempt to connect to my JMS app on openliberty.

[image: Error in JMSToolBox]

When this happens, on the openliberty side the following gets included in message.log.

```
[21/11/22 16:32:11:341 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0010I: Performing recovery processing for local WebSphere server (myCoolServer).
[21/11/22 16:32:11:372 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0012I: All persistent services have been directed to perform recovery processing for this WebSphere server (MyCoolServer).
[21/11/22 16:32:11:372 NZDT] 0000006a com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager                          I WTRN0135I: Transaction service recovering no transactions.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:414 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/MyCoolNotificationIn on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:414 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/MyCoolNotificationInbound will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/MyCoolNotificationIn.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:415 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/MyCoolNotificationInbound and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar# is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:420 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/ on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:420 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/ will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:420 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/ and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar#RecipientNotificationConsumer is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:426 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/ on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:426 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/ will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/ .
[21/11/22 16:32:11:426 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/ and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar# is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:432 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/ on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:432 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/ will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/ .
[21/11/22 16:32:11:432 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/ and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar# is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:437 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/ on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:437 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/ will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/ .
[21/11/22 16:32:11:437 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/ and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar# is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:444 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine defaultME for destination jms/cool/queue/ on bus defaultBus has been successfully created.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:444 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification jms/cool/as/ will now be able to receive the messages from destination jms/cool/queue/ .
[21/11/22 16:32:11:444 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification jms/cool/as/ and message driven bean application notification-manager#MyCoolNotificationService.jar#NotificationConsumer is activated.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:452 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [adminCenter-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, batch-1.0, beanValidation-1.1, cdi-1.2, concurrent-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, ejb-3.2, ejbHome-3.2, ejbLite-3.2, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, ejbRemote-3.2, el-3.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jacc-1.5, jaspic-1.1, javaMail-1.5, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, jaxrs-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, jaxws-2.2, jca-1.7, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jdbc-4.1, jms-2.0, jmsMdb-3.2, jndi-1.0, jpa-2.1, jpaContainer-2.1, jsf-2.2, json-1.0, jsonp-1.0, jsp-2.3, managedBeans-1.0, mdb-3.2, monitor-1.0, mpConfig-1.4, mpMetrics-2.3, restConnector-2.0, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, transportSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsServer-1.0, webProfile-7.0, websocket-1.1].
[21/11/22 16:32:11:452 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 10.158 seconds.
[21/11/22 16:32:11:452 NZDT] 00000031 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The MyCoolServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The MyCoolServer server started in 10.774 seconds.
[21/11/22 16:32:22:089 NZDT] 0000003e com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.sib.core.exception.SIConnectionLostException: CWSIJ0053E: A network connection was terminated after the peer sent incorrectly formatted information. com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.InboundTransmissionParser 00170002" at ffdc_22.11.21_16.32.22.0.log
[21/11/22 16:32:22:143 NZDT] 00000074 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.JFapConnectionBrokenException: CWSIJ0051E: An unexpected condition caused a network connection from host 127.0.0.1 using chain InboundBasicMessaging to close. com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener.errorOccurred 3-001-0001" at ffdc_22.11.21_16.32.22.1.log
```

In the log referred to by the above I get the following:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [21/11/22 16:22:34:728 NZDT]
Exception = com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.JFapConnectionBrokenException
Source = com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener.errorOccurred
probeid = 3-001-0001
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.JFapConnectionBrokenException: CWSIJ0051E: An unexpected condition caused a network connection from host 127.0.0.1 using chain InboundBasicMessaging to close.
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.server.impl.InboundConnection.invalidateImpl(InboundConnection.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.Connection.nonThreadSafeInvalidate(Connection.java:1186)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.Connection.invalidate(Connection.java:1164)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.InboundTransmissionParser.parse(InboundTransmissionParser.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.ConnectionReadCompletedCallback.complete(ConnectionReadCompletedCallback.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.Connection.startNewConversationGeneric(Connection.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.server.impl.InboundConnection.startNewConversation(InboundConnection.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.server.impl.JFapInboundConnLink.ready(JFapInboundConnLink.java:212)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:514)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1057)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.sib.core.exception.SIConnectionLostException: CWSIJ0053E: A network connection was terminated after the peer sent incorrectly formatted information.
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.InboundTransmissionParser.parsePrimaryHeader(InboundTransmissionParser.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.InboundTransmissionParser.parse(InboundTransmissionParser.java:213)
    ... 14 more

Dump of callerThis
Object type = com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener
  CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener"
  tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@1d7ca9dc
    strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener,class com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.server.GenericTransportReceiveListener,[SIBCommunications],com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.CWSICMessages,null]"
  nls = class com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@a16318c4
    resolver = class com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceNLSResolver@b415991e
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@ac5c1b4b
      DEBUG_TRACE_NLS_PROPERTY = "com.ibm.ejs.ras.debugTraceNLSResolver"
      debugTraceNLSResolver = false
```

Below is my server.xml

```
<server description="MyCool Server EAR Server.xml">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>mpMetrics-2.3</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <remoteFileAccess>
        <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <orb id="defaultOrb" orbSSLInitTimeout="40">
        <serverPolicy.csiv2>
            <layers>
                <attributeLayer identityAssertionEnabled="false" />
                <authenticationLayer mechanisms="LTPA"
                    establishTrustInClient="Supported" />
                <transportLayer
                    sslEnabled="true" />
            </layers>
        </serverPolicy.csiv2>
    </orb>
    
  <!-- default SSL configuration is defaultSSLSettings -->
  <sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLSettings" />
  
  <ssl id="defaultSSLSettings"
       keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
       clientAuthenticationSupported="true" />
  <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore"
            location="keystore.jks"
            type="JKS" password="defaultPWD" />

    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="coolRealm">
        <user name="MyCoolUsername" password="MyCoolPassword" />
            ...
        
        <group name="coolGroup">
            <member name="coolMember" />
            ...
        </group>
        
    </basicRegistry>
    
    <administrator-role>
        <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>
    <reader-role>
        <user>reader</user>
    </reader-role>

    <!-- jndi-1.0 - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=dmdbwl-deploying-message-driven-beans-connect-embedded-messaging-server -->

    <!-- START JMS CONFIGURATION -->

    <wasJmsEndpoint id="InboundJmsCommsEndpoint"
        wasJmsPort="9126" wasJmsSSLPort="9127" />

    <connectionManager id="ConMgr3" maxPoolSize="5" />

    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory
        jndiName="jndi_JMS_BASE-QCF" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr6">
        <properties.wasJms />
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

    <connectionManager id="ConMgr6" maxPoolSize="5" />

    <messagingEngine>
        ... queues ....
    </messagingEngine>

    <!-- RecipientNotificationConsumerCRELarge -->
    <jmsQueue id="coolQueue"
        ...
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="xxx">
        ...
    </jmsActivationSpec>

    <enterpriseApplication id="cool-manager"
        type="ear" location="MyCoolServiceEAR.ear"
        name="myCoolService" contextRoot="/" />

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="${default.http.port}"
        httpsPort="${default.https.port}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />
</server>
```

Here's my JMSToolBox configuration

[image: JMSToolBox Configuration]

And the properties tab

[image]

I have a few theories about why this may be happening. However, they may be wild goose chases, so I'm hoping to get a steer from someone out there who knows this stuff well.

Comment: My guess would be that you are trying to make SSL connection to the non-ssl port.
You really need to add `server.xml` to the question and params that you use to establish connection.

Comment: Thanks @Gas. I've added server.xml and JMSToolBox config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misconfiguration.

Your JMS server is configured like this:

```
<wasJmsEndpoint id="InboundJmsCommsEndpoint"
    wasJmsPort="9126" wasJmsSSLPort="9127" />
```

So your ports are 9126 for basic and 9127 for secure, so your connection should be:

- `localhost:9126:BootstrapSecureMessaging` - for plain
- `localhost:9127:BootstrapSecureMessaging` - for ssl port